# Как выбрать элемент у которого отсутствует элемент ?(xpath)

Tags: xpath

Нужно выбрать элемент с надписью "Подробнее" где нет надписи "Еще" они находятся на блоке //*[@data-test="grid-row"] . Какой xpath нужно написать ?
[image]

Код элемента с элементом "Подробнее" и "еще":
[image: Код элемента с элементом "Подробнее"]

Код элемента с элементом "Подробнее" и без "еще":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ссылка на сайт](https://www.banki.ru/products/deposits/search/saratov/?page=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//div[@data-test="grid-row"]
/div[1][not(descendant::span[@data-role="link"
 and child::span[1][contains(text(), "Еще")]])]
/following-sibling::*[4]//span[contains(text(), "Подробнее")]
```

Неэстетично, но вроде работает.

Comment: Спасибо, я долго голову ломал))

Answer (score 0):

В ФФ правая кнопка на нужном элементе, выбрать "Исследовать элемент" или как оно будет на русском, в левом нижнем окне будет подствечен соответсвующий код, правая кнопка, "Копировать"  - XPath.

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/a[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/button
```

В Хроме то же самое, примерно такими же действиями.

Comment: только это не тот элемент https://ibb.co/JzC1ddV. И нужно выбрать все подобные элементы.

Comment: Нужный элемент находиться на первой картинке сверху по середине

Comment: Понятно, что не тот. Я же не буду выискивать там тот банк, который у вас на скриншоте. Все подобные берутся в цикле.

Comment: Я имею виду нужен элемент не с кнопкой "Подробнее". А нужен элемент у которого подробнее находиться под кнопкой "Узнать больше" и слева нет элемента "Еще"

Comment: Я вам описал, как получить xpath к любому элементу.

Comment: Эникейщик  - Однако это не является ответом на заданный вопрос